Specific Raspberry Pi version?
Is this the place for me to ask about "which Pi version or model will accomplish the tasks needed?
I have already tried asking this, with a litanny of tasks I'm wanting to accomplish, but that question was banned for being too vague and unclear.
Even after a few edit and "bolding" the primary point of my topic.
Really looking for some actual assistance please.
Thank you.

"which Pi version or model will accomplish the tasks needed?" We aren't psychic! See Tour to see how this site works
and How do I ask a good question?

This (the "meta" site for raspberrypi.stackexchange) is the place to ask questions about the site itself such as this one, which is why I moved your question here.
You may ask on the main site about which models are more and less appropriate for a specific task, but:

If it is simply a question of processing power and memory usage (which it usually is), then you might as well just ask which models have enough (which is pretty easy to check yourself).
If it is really because you don't know what resources a task requires, then you should ask about that and not which model of Pi to use.  Depending on the task, this may be an appropriate place, but most will probably be better on Unix & Linux or Super User or possibly Stack Overflow, if it is programming/development related.

That said, if you have already been received badly, rather than just asking if you can ask again and whining about how unhelpful people were the last time, you should ask specifically what was wrong with your question and how it could be improved.  If you are constantly taking criticism like this personally, you are going to have an awkward and unpleasant experience seeking technical help online from a volunteer audience and would probably better off consulting chatGPT or similar.  Other people do not like being asked to regurgitate information such as how many cores a Pi model has and how fast they are when this can be looked up easily online -- and some of will tell you that for good reason.  However, an AI will happily regurgitate such information all day.

Can I quote for you here, my original question?  If doing so, could you please point out to me what was wrong with it?

Yes, but please put it in a new question; a guideline/policy here is not to take a question and turn it into another question after it has been answered, because this invalids the answers.  Before you do that, though, read What does it matter that my question is "unclear" or "too broad", etc?.
